# AspectJ generates two different byte codes (with Java) when other parameters are same

Tags: java

Following versions maintained in pom.xml    :
aspectj version     :     1.8.2
aspectj maven plugin    :    1.7
java version    :     1.7

After every compilation and **aspectj** weaving, generated byte code is different. (It is compilation time aspect weaving).

Expected, if nothing changes - from java compiler, maven, **aspectj** runtime library etc - generated byte code always should be same.

If **aspectj** is excluded, then generated byte code is same.

Any help?

Explanation    : 
Say my project generates a jar file named -  amodule.jar.

Taking two jar files from two consecutive compilations, I extracted in two places. Then I generated SHA1 keys for every class file and compared two SHA1 key lists and found different keys for many class files. Now java class files, showing differences in SHA1 key, were decompiled into java programs. Decompiled java program differences may be described mainly in two categories (a) shifting or displacement of try - catch block randomly and renaming exception variables within catch block; (b) In some cases not able to translate into java programs and keeping the original byte code in generated java programs.

Generated java programs may be defective due to inefficiency of decompiler. But different SHA1 key for the same class file in two consecutive compilation is the proof of different byte code.

Of course above mentioned difference happens only when Aspectj is included (-Daspect.skip=false used in java compilation command line). If Aspects is excluded, SHA1 key comparison report shows no difference.

Comment: What is the difference between the two versions of the bytecode?   Why it is a problem that there is a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that that the bytecodes themselves (not just the .class files) appear to be different.  This could be explained by the Aspectj weaver not being entirely deterministic.  For example, if it used hash tables in some part of the compilation processes, and the hash keys have identity hashcodes, then iteration of the hash table data structure is liable to visit elements in a different order from one compilation to the next.  This could cause differences in the generated bytecodes, constants pool and so on.

If this is the cause of the problem there is probably no practical solution.

---

Concerning the evidence.  If I understand you correctly, the differences you are seeing are actually differences in the ".class" files; i.e. they have different SHA-1 hashes.

> Decompiled java program differences may be described mainly in two categories (a) shifting or displacement of try - catch block randomly and renaming exception variables within catch block;

It is possible that some of these differences that you are seeing in decompiled code are due to use of hash tables in the decompiler.  This is not definitively evidence of bytecode differences.

> In some cases not able to translate into java programs and keeping the original byte code in generated java programs.

This is not evidence of anything.  It is common for decompiled code to not be compileable.  And note that you are attempting to decompile / recompile code that has been "woven", which may be confusing the decompiler.

You should probably be using `javap -c` or doing a forensic analysis of the byte code to determine what the ".class" file differences *really* are.